When I try to change the primaryColor in the Theme.kt in Jetpack Compose android application its not changing the color in UI
When I try to change the primaryColor of the application in the Theme.kt in Jetpack Compose android application its not changing the color in UI.I am applying the color to TopAppBar
colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors( containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary, navigationIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary, actionIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary)

I am changing the primary color in the my apps Theme.kt file
darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80)

But color not changing in the UI

provide code in your Theme.kt file

Please make sure that you're using the Theme in your MainActivity
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            //here under the setContent, you should have been using the Theme.
            YourTheme { 
                YourMainUi()
            }
        }
    }
}

To make Previews reflect the theme, you should also use it inside your preview composables.
@Composable
@Preview
fun MyScreenPreview() {
    YourTheme {
        MyScreen()
    }
}


Make sure:

Your testing device is in Dark Mode. Just in case, try changing the lightColorScheme colors too.
Your testing device is not using Dynamic Color. This feature overrides the app's defined colors.
You are using "your app's theme" and not the generic one.

Change this:
MaterialTheme {

        // UI content

    }

To this:
YourAppNameMaterialTheme {

        // UI content

    }


Worked after changing true to false in the Theme.kt dynamicColor: Boolean = false,
